# How to focus specific input elements in Ember 2

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I am learning Ember 2, and trying to write a simple inline editor. My problem is auto-focusing the input element. The component's template is as follows:

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Line item" autofocus="autofocus" value=value class="form-control" focus-out="save"}}
{{/if}}
{{#unless isEditing}}
    <a href="#" {{action "toggleEditor"}}>{{value}}</a>
{{/unless}}
```

With the controller being:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        toggleEditor: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', !this.get('isEditing'));
        },
        save: function () {
            var object = this.get('object');
            var property = this.get('property');
            object.set(property, this.get('value'));
            var promise = object.save();
            promise.finally(() => {
                this.send('toggleEditor');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Using `autofocus="autofocus"` works when setting the `isEditing` parameter to true. However, when the anchor element is visible, and the user clicks on the link, the focus won't transfer to the newly visible input element. My question therefore is: what's the best way of focusing the input element? Inside `toggleEditor`, how do I access the input element by ID and how can I focus it using Ember?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a better way to toggle properties.

```
this.toggleProperty('propertyName');
```

Also consider using if/else.

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Line item" class="my-input"}}
{{else}}
    <a href="#" {{action "toggleEditor"}}>{{value}}</a>
{{/if}}
```

The way i got it working was to write an action like this.

```
toggleIsEditing: function() {
        this.toggleProperty('isEditing');

        if(this.get('isEditing')) {
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
                $('.my-input').focus();
            });  
        }
},
```

Weird stuff tho.

Comment: Thank you Kristjan! That worked. And nice one re `toggleProperty` :)